# How can I update a data

Tags: c#, sql, sql-update, adapter

I filled a dataset using a Select query with InnerJoin but **all fields are from one table**. How can I update this table using DataAdapter.update() andCommandBuilder?

This is the Fill code:

```
// Get data from database
dstUsers = new DataSet();
string Query = @"SELECT Users.Firstname
                , Users.Lastname
                , Users.Fathername
                , Users.CodeMelli
                , Users.Tel
                , Users.Mobile
                , Users.Tahol

                FROM KarvanUsers INNER JOIN
                Users ON KarvanUsers.Users_id = Users.Id INNER JOIN
                Karvan ON KarvanUsers.Karvan_id = Karvan.Id
                WHERE (Karvan.Id = 1)";

adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Query, connection);

connection.Open();
adapter.Fill(dstUsers,"Users");
connection.Close();
```

Comment: The selected columns are from one table, but the query is based on 3 tables (KarvanUsers, Users, and Karvan).

Comment: I don't know if that query is compatible with SqlCommandBuilder, but the documentation says the select command must return a primary key or unique column so try adding Users.Id into the result set. Or better yet, don't use command builder. Its not that hard to write an update.

Comment: How can I update database for all rows with a single query?

Comment: @rostamiani if you don't use a WHERE clause or JOIN, an update will affect all rows in the table. There are many SQL tutorials available online.

Comment: @Crowcoder I know SQL. But I don't know how can I do multiple row updates with different contents at the same time.

Comment: @rostamiani you only need one update statement, the data adapter manages row state and changes so you need only call adapter.Update.

Comment: @Crowcoder Thanks, but I could not find how? where should I add this Update command?

Comment: @rostamiani Google for "using SqlDataAdapters" should give a ton of info. Or [see my blog](http://contrivedexample.com/2015/03/14/a-basic-example-of-crud-with-datagridview-in-vb-net/) for a VB.Net example - the principal is the same as with c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Crowcoder I added Insert, Update and delete commands like this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Form2 frm = new Form2();
    //frm.Show();
    users_ofTableAdapter.Fill(this.karvanDataSet.Users_of, 1);

    // Config data adapter for updating database
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Settings.Default.KarvanConnectionString);

    String sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Users] ([Firstname], [Lastname], [Fathername], [CodeMelli], [Tel], [Mobile], [Tahol], [ImagePath]) VALUES (@Firstname, @Lastname, @Fathername, @CodeMelli, @Tel, @Mobile, @Tahol, @ImagePath)";
    String sqlUpdate = "UPDATE [dbo].[Users] SET [Firstname] = @Firstname, [Lastname] = @Lastname, [Fathername] = @Fathername, [CodeMelli] = @CodeMelli, [Tel] = @Tel, [Mobile] = @Mobile, [Tahol] = @Tahol, [ImagePath] = @ImagePath WHERE ([Id] = @Original_Id)";
    String sqlDelete = "DELETE FROM [dbo].[Users] WHERE (([Id] = @Original_Id)";

    SqlCommand cmdInsert = new SqlCommand(sqlInsert, connection);
    SqlCommand cmdUpdate = new SqlCommand(sqlUpdate, connection);
    SqlCommand cmdDelete = new SqlCommand(sqlDelete, connection);

    SqlParameter myparam = new SqlParameter();


    cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@Firstname", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30, "Firstname");
    cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@Lastname", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30, "Lastname");
    cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@Fathername", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30, "Fathername");
    cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@CodeMelli", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30, "CodeMelli");
    cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@Tel", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30, "Tel");
    cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@Mobile", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30, "Mobile");
    cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@Tahol", SqlDbType.TinyInt, 1, "Tahol");
    cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@ImagePath", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30, "ImagePath");
    //cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@DateAdded", SqlDbType.DateTime, "DateAdded");

    cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@Firstname", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30, "Firstname");
    cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@Lastname", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30, "Lastname");
    cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@Fathername", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30, "Fathername");
    cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@CodeMelli", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30, "CodeMelli");
    cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@Tel", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30, "Tel");
    cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@Mobile", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30, "Mobile");
    cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@Tahol", SqlDbType.TinyInt, 1, "Tahol");
    cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@ImagePath", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30, "ImagePath");
    //cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@DateAdded", SqlDbType.DateTime, "DateAdded");
    cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@Original_Id", SqlDbType.Int, 2, "id");

    cmdDelete.Parameters.Add("@Original_Id", SqlDbType.Int, 2, "id");

    users_ofTableAdapter.Adapter.InsertCommand = cmdInsert;
    users_ofTableAdapter.Adapter.UpdateCommand = cmdUpdate;
    users_ofTableAdapter.Adapter.DeleteCommand = cmdDelete;
}

private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    users_ofTableAdapter.Adapter.Update(karvanDataSet);
}
```